# non-unique values when setting 'row.names' - just ignore?

Tags: r

Is there any way to ignore that ? It's ok for me to put the same name of the row for different rows. If it's not possible is there any way to put just additional ".2" to the rows which are duplicated ?

Comment: Why do you need to set row.names?

Comment: Just to have a proper names on the heat maps.

Comment: Provide a reproducible example and I'm sure we can help you.

Comment: For what do you need a reproducible example ? Just to not downvote me ? Just answer on the simple question... That's really hard ?

Comment: It's easier with a reproducible example. It's just polite to make it easier to help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be able to modify the names so that they are unique.  Here is an example:

```
x <- c(rep(1,5), 2, 3, 4, rep(5, 2), 1)
x
## [1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 3 4 5 5 1
```

You can create a disambiguating vector with `ave`:

```
ave(x, x, FUN=function(i) seq(length(i)))
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5 1 1 1 1 2 6
```

Paste this to the values in `x` and you have unique values:

```
paste(x, ave(x, x, FUN=function(i) seq(length(i))), sep='.')
##  [1] "1.1" "1.2" "1.3" "1.4" "1.5" "2.1" "3.1" "4.1" "5.1" "5.2" "1.6"
```

Answer (score 1):

In general you can set rownames as duplicates if you want, see e.g.

```
m <- matrix(1:9,3,3)
rownames(m) <- c(1,1,1)
m
  [,1] [,2] [,3]
#1    1    4    7
#1    2    5    8
#1    3    6    9
```

I'm not sure why this isn't permitted for data.frames, e.g.

```
d <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=letters[1:10])
rownames(d) <- rep(letters[1:5],2)
#Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
#  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
#In addition: Warning message:
#non-unique values when setting 'row.names': ‘a’, ‘b’, ‘c’, ‘d’, ‘e’
```

Giving an example of the type of object that you're thinking of may lead to a more specific answer.